unable to install ros2
I am new with ubuntu and ros2
I am following the link
jazzy jalisco
I would learn ros2
...$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble
...$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
stefa24@DESKTOP-MLS16HB:~$    

but i am facing ERR and Failure
...$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
Adding component(s) 'universe' to all repositories.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

again here
...$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install ros-dev-tools
Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu noble InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.ros.org'
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.ros.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-dev-tools

and here
...$ sudo apt install ros-jazzy-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jazzy-desktop


Your system appears to have the DNS resolvers incorrectly setup such that no hosts can be resolved. You need to make sure your system has the DNS resolving before you can try to run the installation instructions. Otherwise none of the commands will work that need external resources, which will prevent the installation process.
Setting up your DNS is out of scope for this forum. You'll want to reach out to your system administrator or look on Linux networking forums.
